# TCP/IP convert signal to virtual USB

Tags: windows-7, conversion

I have car diagnostic tool which connects through network adapter, and I have software which connects only through USB.

How can I redirect from network to virtual usb ?

OS: Win XP, Win 7

Comment: Much too vague. Which software? What have you tried?

Comment: I only need that software will think that I connected diagnostic tool through USB. Soft is VCDS

Comment: Can you give additional details about what you mean when you say the software requires USB? Is it saying it needs a COM port/Serial Port? Cause that's not quite USB. The reason I ask is USB isn't usually accessed directly by software. Instead, it allows the device it's connecting to register itself with the computer so that software can identify and communicate with the end-point device "directly."

Comment: Also, are you _certain_ that the car diagnostic tool is using network protocols? An 8P8C connector (commonly called RJ45) can be used for many things, not all of them network related. They are common in serial communication over large distances, which would make more sense for the kind of device we are talking about.

Comment: I meant, "Which software are you using"? Not what are you looking for. What is the "car diagnostic tool" you are using?

Comment: diagnostic tool ELM327 wifi, Software only connects through USB, I can't select any COM port or something ...